# MergeOption Usage Examples in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Am new to EF and am trying to understand the updated concepts as am getting old data to use EFextensions  etc..(mostly) when I search in Google.

Am trying to execute a SQL query using `ExecuteStoreQuery.`

I have something called `MergeOption`. What exactly does it do?

I have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.mergeoption.aspx

But am not understanding it clearly. Some examples will take me through.

Thanks,
Peru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the `MergeOption` with `ExecuteStoreQuery` allows you to determine how results will be tracked as entities. As you read in the article you referenced, there are four options:

- `AppendOnly` (default)
- `OverwriteChanges`
- `PreserveChanges`
- `NoTracking`

Here are a couple of links ([basic example](http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2010/02/16/setting-entity-framework-mergeoptions-what-works-what-doesn-t.aspx), [detailed example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/12/ef-merge-options-and-compiled-queries.aspx)) that show some in-depth examples of MergeOption is use, and its impact on the objects being tracked.